# multiprocessing problem [pyqt, py2exe]

Tags: python, pyqt, multiprocessing, py2exe

I am writing a GUI program using PyQt4. 
There is a button in my main window
and by clicking this button.
I hope to launch a background process 
which is an instance of a class derived 
from processing.Process.

```
class BackgroundTask(processing.Process):
    def __init__(self, input):
        processing.Process.__init__(self)
        ...

    def run(self):
        ...
```

(Note that I am using the Python2.5 port
of the python-multiprocessing obtained
from 
http://code.google.com/p/python-multiprocessing/
that is why it is processing.Process
instead of multiprocessing.Process.
I guess this should not make a difference.
Am I right?)

The code connected to the button click signal 
is something simply like

```
 processing.freezeSupport()
 task = BackgroundTask(input)
 task.start()
```

The program works as expected under the python intepreter, i.e.
if it is started from the command line "python myapp.py".

However, after I package the program using py2exe, 
everytime when I click that button, instead
of starting the background task, a copy
of the main window pops up. I am not sure 
what is the reason of this behavior. I guess
it is related to the following note addressed
at 
http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming

"Functionality within this package requires that the **main** method be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the multiprocessing.Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter
"

The only place I have if **name** == "**main**" is in the main module 
as in a typical pyqt program

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QObject.connect(a,SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"),a,SLOT("quit()"))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    a.exec_()
```

Any solutions on how to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify: have you protected the main module as described in the multiprocessing docs? or don't you have access to the main module (I don't know how pyqt works)? it's also worth checking that you're using the latest version of py2exe. I've had problems in the past that turned out to have been caused by out of date py2app/py2exe

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just added the __name__ == "__main__" part in my post. Not sure if I am protecting the main module or not.  The latest version of py2exe I found from http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/ was released on 2008-11-16 so I think I am using the latest version of py2exe.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think your actual problem has to do with this:

> The program works as expected under the python intepreter, i.e. if it is started from the command line "python myapp.py".
>
> However, after I package the program using py2exe, every time when I click that button, > instead of starting the background task, a copy of the main window pops up.

You need to add a special call to the freeze_support() function to make the multiprocessing module work with "frozen" executables (eg, those made with py2exe):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # add freeze support
    processing.freeze_support()
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QObject.connect(a,SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"),a,SLOT("quit()"))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    a.exec_()
```

Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support

Comment: +1: Ran into the exact same problem some time ago, used the exact same fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! I was aware of this freeze_support() function but I did not put it in the right place. Instead of putting it before a = QApplication(sys.argv), I put it every time before a new process instance is created, which seems does not work.

Answer (score 0):

"Functionality within this package requires that the main method be importable by the children."

I think this means you have to have main() function defined somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The question is concerning Python 2 and was solved. For Python 3, it would look like:

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()

    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ...
```