# Multiple Windows with a Multithreaded pyqt application

Tags: python, pyqt4, multiprocessing, py2exe

I wrote a small multiprocessing application and then wrote a PyQt front end for it.  When I run the script by calling it from the command line with Python (or by calling run from the Spyder IDE), it runs exactly as I would expect and works nicely.

But if I try to use Py2Exe to make an executable to give it to a friend, it starts behaving oddly.  When the users hits the botton that really starts the process and invokes the multithreading portion, it spawns multiple Qt windows that look like the original.  It then essentially locks up.  Closing one of the new windows that it spawns causes it to reopen that window.  Attempting to close the original generates a message that it is not responding.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions about where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive about this without looking at your code, but there are some extra considerations when using Py2Exe with multithreading.

Take a look at [this link](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze%5Fsupport) and maybe it has something to do with your problem.

Someone has a similar sounding issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073942/multiprocessing-problem-pyqt-py2exe?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks.  I needed to add in the multiprocessing.freeze_support() command.